# I'm told that no graph can have the following chromatic polynomial, but why not?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, coloring

This style of question has been recurring in my discrete 2 math class, though I consistently struggle with it so I will pick a few past homework problems:

$1.)\text{ }P(G, k) = (k^6-8k^5+13k^4-15k^3+12k^2-6k+3)$

$2.)\text{ }P(G, k) = (k^6-8k^5+13k^4-15k^3+12k^2-6k)$

$3.)\text{ }P(G, k) = (k(k-1)(k-3)^2(k-4))$

We have spent enough time covering chromatic polynomials in the context of graph theory that I know/have proven the following statements to be true:

The coefficient on the starting $k^n$ term must be $1$

The coefficient of the $k^{n-1}$ term must be negative

The exponent $n$ of the first term describes the number of vertices of the graph

The coefficient of the second term $k^{n-1}$ describes the number of edges of the graph

We can never have a "floating" constant

The sum of coefficients of any possible chromatic polynomial is equal to $0$

In the case of number $1$, we have a floating constant which would imply that if $k=0$, there are $3$ ways to $0$-color graph $G$. We know that saying we can assign $0$-colors to a graph in $3$ different ways makes no sense, thus the chromatic polynomial cannot belong to any graph $G$.

In the case of number $2$, we know that we are examining a proposed graph $G$ that has $6$ vertices and $8$ edges. If nothing else, we know that a graph on $6$ vertices is $6$-colorable; no matter how/if they are connected, we know that assigning a different color to each vertex will give us a proper coloring. But when $k=6, P(G,k)=-1548$. We must be able to $6$-color a graph of $6$ vertices in $P(G,k)$ different ways (where $P(G,k)$ must be a positive integer). Thus, the chromatic polynomial cannot belong to any graph $G$.

Number $3$ is then where I'm stumped. Not only is it in a factored form, but no previous methods for determining chromatic polynomial "impossibility" have proven to be successful. When I multiplied it out, all of the conditions listed above held.

Are my justifications for #$1$ and #$2$ sufficient and logical? If so, what am I missing in number $3$?

Additionally, if anyone has general tips for solving these kinds of problems (especially when the chromatic polynomial is in its factored form) please let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arguments are correct for the first two.

For the third one, evaluate at $k=2$ and see what happens.  Another approach is to note that the coefficients imply that $G$ has $5$ nodes and $11$ edges, but $11>\binom{5}{2}$.

Comment: When I evaluate #3 at k=2, I find P(G, k)=(-4). k=5 yields the first non-negative integer. I know we cannot 2-color G in -4 ways, so how does that help me? I do understand your second approach, however, as a fully connected graph on 5 vertices has at MOST 10 edges (k5), which would disprove the validity of the chromatic polynomial. I am interested where you were going with k=2, though, if you could please offer some more clarification!

Comment: For every nonnegative integer $k$, the value of $P(G,k)$ must be a nonnegative integer because (by definition of chromatic polynomial) it is the number of proper $k$-colorings.,

Comment: It's my understanding that the first k such that P(G,k)>0 is the first possible coloring of the graph. If you are arguing that a graph on 5 vertices with 11 edges must be 2-colorable but the polynomial is telling us it's not, I do not see why we should assume it is 2-colorable, to begin with.

Comment: Yes, the smallest nonnegative integer $k$ such that $P(G,k)>0$ is the chromatic number.  But it is also true that $P(G,k)\ge 0$ for all nonnegative $k$ because it is the number of $k$-colorings (possibly $0$ but not negative).

Comment: Now I see--thank you very much. Then, if I were to be asked this type of problem down the road and k=n yields a negative integer P(G, n), it's sufficient to just stop here and say that P(G, n) must be ≥0 (and it's not), so the chromatic polynomial cannot belong to graph G?

Comment: Yes that is a correct argument.